# cannot create forloop array php

Tags: php, arrays

```
<ul class="selectplanparagraph">
<li>
    <h3><?php echo $comparetxt[0][0]; ?></h3>
    <img width="280" height="80" src="<?php echo $comparetxt[0][1]; ?>" alt="">
    <p><?php echo $comparetxt[0][2]; ?></p>
</li>
<li>
    <h3><?php echo $comparetxt[1][0]; ?></h3>
    <img width="280" height="80" src="<?php echo $comparetxt[1][1]; ?>" alt="">
    <p><?php echo $comparetxt[1][2]; ?></p>
</li>
<li>
    <h3><?php echo $comparetxt[2][0]; ?></h3>
    <img width="280" height="80" src="<?php echo $comparetxt[2][1]; ?>" alt="">
    <p><?php echo $comparetxt[2][2]; ?></p>
</li>
<!-- End .selectplanparagraph --></ul>
```

I would like to loop this instead of having 3 LI with hardcoded positions in array, I'd prefer to make a simple loop. I tried but I failed. This loops with arrays are more complicated than I thought :) at least for me beginner :)

array looks like this:

```
$comparetxt = [ 
    [ "Title 1", "url 1", "text 1" ],
    [ "Title 2", "url 2", "text 2" ],
    [ "Title 3", "url 3", "text 3" ]
];
```

Comment: use PHP foreach : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Can you at least post the code you tried?

Comment: @yes123 I read php manual just today and instantly fell in love. So clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it seems like your array notation is wrong. Try this

```
<?php
$comparetxt = array(
    array('title' => 'Title 1', 'url' => 'www.google.com', 'text' => 'text 1'),
    array('title' => 'Title 2', 'url' => 'www.google.com', 'text' => 'text 2'),
    array('title' => 'Title 3', 'url' => 'www.google.com', 'text' => 'text 3')
);
?>
<ul class="selectplanparagraph">
<?php foreach($comparetxt as $compare) { ?>
<li>
<h3><?php echo $compare['title']; ?></h3>
<img width="280" height="80" src="<?php echo $compare['url']; ?>" alt="">
<p><?php echo $compare['text']; ?></p>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, I think the array syntax is the new PHP short array syntax [added in 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Here is some more info: [https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach ($a as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you write a block of code, it's better to indent each line with 4 spaces to have a better rendering. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
foreach($comparetxt as $compareitem) {
    ?>
    <li>
    <h3><?php echo $compareitem[0]; ?></h3>
    <img width="280" height="80" src="<?php echo $compareitem[1]; ?>" alt="">
    <p><?php echo $compareitem[2]; ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php
}
```